# Need test cases to achieve 85% test coverage

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa, mockito, junit4

While deploying the spring boot App, I'm getting sonar scans issue. To resolve the issue I need to write test coverage 85%. I wrote some test cases for my service layer, but the result of test coverage is still 72.1%. I want some test cases those I can add in my service layer test.

JoinQueryService Layer:

```
@Service
public class JoinQueryService {

    @Resource
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    public List<DeptEmpDto> getCrediProduct(DeptEmpDto input) {
        List<DeptEmpDto> list=null;
        if (!input.getEmpName().isEmpty() && input.getEmpEmail().isEmpty()){
            list = employeeRepository.fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoinByName(input.getEmpName());
        }else if(input.getEmpName().isEmpty() && !input.getEmpEmail().isEmpty()){
            list = employeeRepository.fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoinByEmail(input.getEmpEmail());
        }else if(!input.getEmpName().isEmpty() && !input.getEmpEmail().isEmpty()){
            list = employeeRepository.fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoin(input.getEmpName(), input.getEmpEmail());
        }else {
            throw new EmployeeDataNotFoundException();
        }
        return list;
    }

    public String deleteCreditProduct(DeptEmpDto input){
        if (!input.getEmpName().isEmpty() && input.getEmpEmail().isEmpty()){
            employeeRepository.deleteEmpDeptDataInnerJoinByName(input.getEmpName());
        }else if(input.getEmpName().isEmpty() && !input.getEmpEmail().isEmpty()){
            employeeRepository.deleteEmpDeptDataInnerJoinByEmail(input.getEmpEmail());
        }else if(!input.getEmpName().isEmpty() && !input.getEmpEmail().isEmpty()){
            employeeRepository.deleteEmpDeptDataInnerJoin(input.getEmpName(), input.getEmpEmail());
        }else {
            throw new EmployeeDataNotFoundException();
        }
        return "Deleted Successfully";
    }

}
```

This already written test cases for my service test layer.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class JoinQueryServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private EmployeeRepository mockEmployeeRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private JoinQueryService joinQueryServiceUnderTest;

    @Test
    public void testGetCrediProduct() {
        // Setup
        final DeptEmpDto input = new DeptEmpDto("empDept", "empName", "empEmail", "empAddress");

        // Configure EmployeeRepository.fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoinByName(...).
        final List<DeptEmpDto> list = List.of(new DeptEmpDto("empDept", "empName", "empEmail", "empAddress"));
        when(mockEmployeeRepository.fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoinByName("empName")).thenReturn(list);

        // Configure EmployeeRepository.fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoinByEmail(...).
        final List<DeptEmpDto> list1 = List.of(new DeptEmpDto("empDept", "empName", "empEmail", "empAddress"));
        when(mockEmployeeRepository.fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoinByEmail("empEmail")).thenReturn(list1);

        // Configure EmployeeRepository.fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoin(...).
        final List<DeptEmpDto> list2 = List.of(new DeptEmpDto("empDept", "empName", "empEmail", "empAddress"));
        when(mockEmployeeRepository.fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoin("empName", "empEmail")).thenReturn(list2);

        // Run the test
        final List<DeptEmpDto> result = joinQueryServiceUnderTest.getCrediProduct(input);

        // Verify the results
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetCrediProduct_EmployeeRepositoryFetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoinByNameReturnsNoItems() {
        // Setup
        final DeptEmpDto input = new DeptEmpDto("empDept", "empName", "empEmail", "empAddress");
        when(mockEmployeeRepository.fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoinByName("empName")).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());

        // Run the test
        final List<DeptEmpDto> result = joinQueryServiceUnderTest.getCrediProduct(input);

        // Verify the results
        assertEquals(Collections.emptyList(), result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetCrediProduct_EmployeeRepositoryFetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoinByEmailReturnsNoItems() {
        // Setup
        final DeptEmpDto input = new DeptEmpDto("empDept", "empName", "empEmail", "empAddress");
        when(mockEmployeeRepository.fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoinByEmail("empEmail")).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());

        // Run the test
        final List<DeptEmpDto> result = joinQueryServiceUnderTest.getCrediProduct(input);

        // Verify the results
        assertEquals(Collections.emptyList(), result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetCrediProduct_EmployeeRepositoryFetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoinReturnsNoItems() {
        // Setup
        final DeptEmpDto input = new DeptEmpDto("empDept", "empName", "empEmail", "empAddress");
        when(mockEmployeeRepository.fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoin("empName", "empEmail")).thenReturn(
                Collections.emptyList());

        // Run the test
        final List<DeptEmpDto> result = joinQueryServiceUnderTest.getCrediProduct(input);

        // Verify the results
        assertEquals(Collections.emptyList(), result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeleteCreditProduct() {
        // Setup
        final DeptEmpDto input = new DeptEmpDto("empDept", "empName", "empEmail", "empAddress");

        // Run the test
        final String result = joinQueryServiceUnderTest.deleteCreditProduct(input);

        // Verify the results
        assertEquals("Deleted Successfully", result);
        verify(mockEmployeeRepository).deleteEmpDeptDataInnerJoinByName("empName");
        verify(mockEmployeeRepository).deleteEmpDeptDataInnerJoinByEmail("empEmail");
        verify(mockEmployeeRepository).deleteEmpDeptDataInnerJoin("empName", "empEmail");
    }
}
```

I want more test cases to resolve my issue and coverage should increase from 72.1% to 85% at-least.
Please provide me some more test cases based on above service layer.

Comment: "Please provide me some more test cases based on above service layer." This is _entirely_ missing the point of tests. Writing tests to fit your existing code is like making new marking on your ruler to exactly match a wooden plank you've already cut. Sure the two now match up, but the value is quite minimal.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be fairly difficult to determine this just looking at the code.

However, there's a fantastic IDE plugin for this called SonarLint that will generate a report of test coverage at a granular level.

Step 1. Install the SonarLint plugin in your favorite IDE.

Step 2. Run your application "With Coverage"
[image]

Step 3. View Test Coverage Report
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but above test cases it fully covers only for this method:list = employeeRepository.fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoin(input.getEmpName(), input.getEmpEmail());   and remaining methods are not covered it showed in the sonaarLint. I need help to cover remaining methods also.

Comment: You are aware that in your tests you aren't actually testing anything right? Just asserting an empty list isn't doing anything. The tool might give you a false sense of security that you have high test coverage but anyone actually looked at the tests they would realize they aren't doing anything. I highly recommend you read up on how to use JUnit and Mockito to write effective tests and for now, ignore the percentages. 10% test coverage with well written tests is better than 85% coverage with tests that aren't actually testing anything.